# jQuery Address plugin with jQuery 1.7.x

Tags: jquery-address, jquery-1.7

I have been using jQuery Address for about 1½ years now. This is just to clearify that I know the plugin well, and implementation, events etc. is not an issue.

For a project I have to use redactorJS which requires jQuery 1.7.x and above. This is just to say WHY I have to use 1.7.2 nothing else.

Problem:
jQuery Address breaks (almost) all jQuery plugins when the change event is fired in all jQuery versions above 1.5.x.

Can anyone shed some light as to what is causing this issue on newer jQuery versions?